# Interface for Native Module in Electron-TypeScript-React App

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron, preloadjs, node-native-addon

I'm writing an app that depends on a native Node module using Electron, React and TypeScript. I have context isolation on and am using a preload script to expose the API of the native module onto the global scope. My preload script looks like:

```js
const {contextBridge} = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {basis: require('basis')})
```

In a non-typescript version of my App I can then use it by saying:

```
window.electron.basis["some property of the native module"]
```

However, TypeScript obviously has no notion of the API from the native module. How should I make it aware? The one success I had was in my `index.tsx` putting:

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        electron: { basis: { greeting(): string } };
    }
}
```

But that seems clunky. Should I put a .d.ts file in the native module? Can I export this interface merging to a different file? For reference I am using [Neon](https://neon-bindings.com/) with the N-API backend.